# Wordpress: remove part of post slug in database

Tags: sql, wordpress, slug

I have around 5K posts which slug ends in "-2" (ex: closings-aeropostale-2 )

Would like to remove everything after/including the "-", so final result will look like "closings-aeropostale"

Any suggestions on how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have use same slug two or more times so problem arrived if you want to remove -2 so first you have change the name of closings-aeropostale(**slug**).
then after you can change this (**slug**)closings-aeropostale-2.